# .NET Core 3.1 The JSON value of length n is too large and not supported

Tags: c#, json, rest, .net-core-3.1

I have an application that uses two .NET Core 3.1 applications. The first .NET Core 3.1 application sends a REST HttpPost request to the second .NET Core 3.1 application.

When my second .NET Core solution returns a response to the HttpPost request, I see an exception : The JSON value of length 806376078 is too large and not supported.

I have tried adding to the App.config file :

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

3)

[image]

4. I also tried to add to my startup services :

   services.Configure(options =>
   {
   options.ValueCountLimit = 10; //default 1024
   options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
   options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
   options.MemoryBufferThreshold = Int32.MaxValue;
   });
   services.AddMvc(options =>
   {
   options.MaxModelBindingCollectionSize = int.MaxValue;
   });

or

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().
    AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = Int32.MaxValue;
    });
```

But nothing worked, I still get the exception :

> An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
> System.ArgumentException: The JSON value of length 806376078 is too
> large and not supported.

when I try to return an 806376078 byte array from the second .Net Core 3.1 web service.

Can you recommend some solution or approach for me to try to fix this exception?

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
> Connection id "0HMJQ9OLIK5S4", Request id "0HMJQ9OLIK5S4:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the
> application. System.ArgumentException: The JSON value of length
> 806376078 is too large and not supported.    at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException_ValueTooLarge(Int32
> tokenLength)    at
> System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter.WriteBase64StringValue(ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterByteArray.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Byte[] value, JsonSerializerOptions options)    at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnWriteEnumerable(WriteStackFrame&
> current, Utf8JsonWriter writer)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.WriteEnumerable(WriteStack& state,
> Utf8JsonWriter writer)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleEnumerable(JsonClassInfo
> elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, WriteStack& state)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32
> originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions
> options, WriteStack& state)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object
> value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext
> context, Encoding selectedEncoding)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext
> context, Encoding selectedEncoding)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> application)

Comment: [Does this issue useful to u?](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/40796)

Comment: it seems https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/40796 the article says that the problem was fixed in .NET Core 3.0, but I am using .NET Core 3.1?